# How to define Pydantic Class for nested dictionary

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

How do we define a Pydantic Class Type for the following nested dictionary structure (with complicated strings as keys):

```py
{ "inputs" : {
        "simpleStringName": <Simple_DateTime_Value>
        "simpleStringName2": {
        "Complicated|String|Name|with|Pipe|Characters" : <Simple-Int-Value>,
        "Complicated|String|Name2|with|Pipe|Characters" : <Simple-Int-Value2>
        }
    }
}
```

Pydantic needs to enforce the entire structure. That is simply this will not work:

```py
class XYZ(BaseModel):
    inputs : Dict()
```

I want to enforce requests input format using Pydantic with fastAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you're after

```py
import datetime
from typing import Union, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class XYZ(BaseModel):
    inputs: Dict[str, Union[datetime.datetime, Dict[str, int]]]
```

```py
>>> XYZ(**{
...     "inputs" : {
...         "simpleStringName": datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
...         "simpleStringName2": {
...             "Complicated|String|Name|with|Pipe|Characters" : 3,
...             "Complicated|String|Name2|with|Pipe|Characters" : 4
...         }
...     }
... })
XYZ(inputs={'simpleStringName': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 11, 16, 34, 21, 906156), 'simpleStringName2': {'Complicated|String|Name|with|Pipe|Characters': 3, 'Complicated|String|Name2|with|Pipe|Characters': 4}})
```

If you want to explicitly define the strings, you can use Pydantic's Constrained Types (here `constr` with a regex, but many options are available)
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types

```py
class XYZ(pydantic.BaseModel):
    inputs: Dict[
        pydantic.constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z\d]+$"),
        Union[
            datetime.datetime,
            Dict[
                pydantic.constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z\d\|]+$"),
                int
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Instead of `pydantic.constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z\d]+$")`, can I directly mention the string_name? I presume `regex="fully_qualified_string_name"` solves the purpose anyway?

Comment: I'm actually not sure; there may be some cleaner method to name your fields as impossible Python identifiers (even just a humble int like `5` is problematic), but it's not overtly obvious - Pydantic is somewhat new to me and I'd honestly try to disallow field names which cannot be Python identifiers and expect complex data to be base64-encoded or throw out JSON entirely for some flexible binary format .. Yes! you can just write an explicit regex if you know the exact field name (you can also use `re.escape(my_str)` to automatically escape control chars like your pipe marks when generating it!)

Comment: To elaborate a little more, if you're certain what the string is, there's often not a lot of reason for it to be so complex (ie. is `"stringname2"` sufficient?) and pack any extra information about it into some documentation string (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/ ) .. and if you're not certain what a field will be named, you can instead have an explicit name and data field like `{"name": "Complicated|String|Name2|with|Pipe|Characters", "data": <Simple-Int-Value2>}` rather than attempting to pair them each time